# How to transform annual data into quarterly?

Tags: r, xts

I have a `xts` object with annual data. I would like to convert this in quarterly data, the values will keep the same over the year, so, I don't have to interpolate the data.

I tried `apply.quarterly` and `to.quarterly`, but the data is still yearly.

Here's my code:

```
library(xts)

apply.quarterly(x, FUN = mean)
```

My output:

```
            Cons_gov      FBKF
1996-12-01 0.1975085 0.1864072
1997-12-01 0.1953536 0.1912290
1998-12-01 0.2007051 0.1854231
1999-12-01 0.1978274 0.1701628
2000-12-01 0.1876777 0.1830450
2001-12-01 0.1934325 0.1841800
2002-12-01 0.1980967 0.1792619
2003-12-01 0.1907744 0.1660478
2004-12-01 0.1846763 0.1732019
2005-12-01 0.1888999 0.1705619
2006-12-01 0.1903895 0.1721032
2007-12-01 0.1894298 0.1799576
2008-12-01 0.1883942 0.1938534
2009-12-01 0.1965066 0.1910200
2010-12-01 0.1901688 0.2053467
2011-12-01 0.1866926 0.2060899
2012-12-01 0.1853010 0.2071671
2013-12-01 0.1889248 0.2091192
2014-12-01 0.1915354 0.1987301
2015-12-01 0.1977682 0.1783580
```

My `dput()`:

```
structure(c(0.197508549153391, 0.195353585641678, 0.200705142210663, 
0.197827364070052, 0.187677686384626, 0.193432520923332, 0.198096706851479, 
0.190774358523613, 0.184676286553441, 0.188899853679931, 0.190389507978999, 
0.189429845570079, 0.188394248767526, 0.1965065515285, 0.190168835777631, 
0.186692569341525, 0.185300994171881, 0.18892479001219, 0.191535387119431, 
0.197768166586277, 0.203792941796483, 0.201619077612893, 0.198950735000909, 
0.200777424344436, 0.204929121903237, 0.183310918318924, 0.186407226330573, 
0.191228971241134, 0.18542307036158, 0.170162846564942, 0.183045018192917, 
0.184180045540359, 0.179261923121358, 0.166047809279776, 0.173201889924658, 
0.170561931719758, 0.172103177073606, 0.179957599687971, 0.193853437018358, 
0.191019967063092, 0.205346736503007, 0.206089870582595, 0.207167084721339, 
0.20911921875888, 0.198730115991599, 0.178358040677889, 0.155243408026601, 
0.145589735475542, 0.150969119553704, 0.153124811412088, 0.16430683828827, 
0.187924188341473), index = structure(c(849398400, 880934400, 
912470400, 944006400, 975628800, 1007164800, 1038700800, 1070236800, 
1101859200, 1133395200, 1164931200, 1196467200, 1228089600, 1259625600, 
1291161600, 1322697600, 1354320000, 1385856000, 1417392000, 1448928000, 
1480550400, 1512086400, 1543622400, 1575158400, 1606780800, 1622505600
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .Dim = c(26L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Cons_gov", "FBKF")))
```

Comment: The problem here is that you need a frequency of 12 in your yearly cycle to be able to collapse it into quarterly.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: the `apply.period` functions roll up the data from a higher frequency to a lower frequency. So, from daily to weekly, or monthly, etc. etc. Not the other way around. There is no data to specify. If you want quarterly you would have to supply your own dates and numbers. Just dividing by 4 is an option, but maybe not correct.

Comment: @AlexandreSanches I think you need a time series where every time point is for example the start of every month of a year. In that way you could aggregate it to quarterly frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform `xts` object into a data frame. Then you can repeat every row of a data.frame given amount of time. I used `dplyr` for data transformations and `lubridate` for date information manipulation, finally I'm transforming it into quarterly format.

See below `xts` object to transform:

```
yearly <- structure(c(0.197508549153391, 0.195353585641678, 0.200705142210663, 
            0.197827364070052, 0.187677686384626, 0.193432520923332, 0.198096706851479, 
            0.190774358523613, 0.184676286553441, 0.188899853679931, 0.190389507978999, 
            0.189429845570079, 0.188394248767526, 0.1965065515285, 0.190168835777631, 
            0.186692569341525, 0.185300994171881, 0.18892479001219, 0.191535387119431, 
            0.197768166586277, 0.203792941796483, 0.201619077612893, 0.198950735000909, 
            0.200777424344436, 0.204929121903237, 0.183310918318924, 0.186407226330573, 
            0.191228971241134, 0.18542307036158, 0.170162846564942, 0.183045018192917, 
            0.184180045540359, 0.179261923121358, 0.166047809279776, 0.173201889924658, 
            0.170561931719758, 0.172103177073606, 0.179957599687971, 0.193853437018358, 
            0.191019967063092, 0.205346736503007, 0.206089870582595, 0.207167084721339, 
            0.20911921875888, 0.198730115991599, 0.178358040677889, 0.155243408026601, 
            0.145589735475542, 0.150969119553704, 0.153124811412088, 0.16430683828827, 
            0.187924188341473), index = structure(c(849398400, 880934400, 
                                                    912470400, 944006400, 975628800, 1007164800, 1038700800, 1070236800, 
                                                    1101859200, 1133395200, 1164931200, 1196467200, 1228089600, 1259625600, 
                                                    1291161600, 1322697600, 1354320000, 1385856000, 1417392000, 1448928000, 
                                                    1480550400, 1512086400, 1543622400, 1575158400, 1606780800, 1622505600
            ), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .Dim = c(26L, 
                                                                                  2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Cons_gov", "FBKF")))
```

Algorithm itself:

```
library(xts)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

quarterly <- as_tibble(yearly, rownames = "dates") %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 4)) %>%
  mutate(years = year(dates)) %>%
  mutate(months = rep((1:4) * 3, times = n() / 4)) %>%
  mutate(dates = ymd(paste0(years, "-", months, "-01"))) %>%
  select(-years, -months) %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "dates") %>%
  as.xts 
xts1 <- to.quarterly(quarterly[, 1])
xts2 <- to.quarterly(quarterly[, 2])
final <- cbind(xts1[, 1], xts2[, 1])
names(final) <- c("Cons_gov", "FBKF")
head(final)
```

Output:

```
         Cons_gov      FBKF
1996 Q1 0.1975085 0.1864072
1996 Q2 0.1975085 0.1864072
1996 Q3 0.1975085 0.1864072
1996 Q4 0.1975085 0.1864072
1997 Q1 0.1953536 0.1912290
1997 Q2 0.1953536 0.1912290
```

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot!